# Why I can't see hdri preview?

Tags: hdri

I have added a HDR environment image. In the 3d View it's visible, but not in *World Properties Preview*.

[image]

With my small scene i added another hdri. I turn off the ray visibility -> camera off. The scene turn black.

[image]

I created a glass cabine. I cant see the glass edge. Here i have a top area light. And same no hdri preview seen. Just complete black.

[image]

Any suggestion how the hdri can be visible and why the glass edge not visible. Thanks

Comment: Preview issue - check answer. Others - It is not clear what are you asking for. When you turn off Camera visibility for World 3D view is black off course, do you expect something different? For the Glass Q, you can try add Bevel modifier, so light can catch on rounded edges, or post simplified blend to let us see.

Answer (score 1):

### Why i cant see preview in the properties view?

Your view shows just grey part of texture. Preview doesn't display whole HDR texture, just view angle. If you go to World node three and change Rotation in Mapping node you can see difference.

[image]